# PayPal .net easiest way to check transaction?

Tags: c#, .net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

After buying on the client side, I want to check the transaction in the backend (.net).

I tried with PayPalCheckoutSDK and could not get it to work (never responde after this line: await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request);)

Is there an easiest way to check the PayPal transaction?

Thanks in advance.

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        OrdersGetRequest request = new OrdersGetRequest(orderId);
        //3. Call PayPal to get the transaction
        var response = await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request);
        //4. Save the transaction in your database. Implement logic to save transaction to your database for future reference.
        var result = response.Result<Order>();
```

Comment: What is the underlying HTTP request being made?

Comment: I dont know because it is managed by the paypal sdk

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to inspect the request.